# Why when I using animation.FuncAnimation returning no image?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the data line by line in a plot.For that I'm using Matplotlib.animation module for it. The code which I'm using is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
    pullData = open("2_4.txt","r").read()
    dataArray = pullData.split('\n')
    xar = []
    yar = []
    for eachLine in dataArray:
        if len(eachLine)>1:
            x,y = eachLine.split(',')
            xar.append(int(x))
            yar.append(int(y))
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xar,yar)
    plt.grid()
    
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)

plt.show()
```

This just returns an
[image: empty plot with no values]
Can someone explain what is wrong in my code?

```
Sample data used
2,3
2,5
3,4
5,6
6,7
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic form of the animation is based on the initial graph setup and the setting of data in the animation function. So, from your code, the initial settings are taken out of the animation function. Here we specify an empty list. Next, set the drawing range for the animation axes. In the animation function, since it is a line graph, update the data with set_data(). My environment is jupyterLab and I've installed some libraries for attachment. Please ignore them as I have commented them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time
# from IPython.display import HTML
# from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1 = plt.axes(xlim =(0, 7), ylim =(0, 7)) 
pullData = open("2_4.txt","r").read()
dataArray = pullData.split('\n')
xar = []
yar = []
lines, = ax1.plot([], [], 'r-', lw=2)

def animate(i):
    eachLine = dataArray[i]
    if len(eachLine)>1:
        x,y = eachLine.split(',')
        xar.append(int(x))
        yar.append(int(y))
    lines.set_data(xar, yar)
    ax1.grid(True)
    
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=5, interval=1000)
ani.save('line_ani3.gif', writer='pillow')
plt.show()
# plt.close()
# HTML(ani.to_html5_video())
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the `animation` function gives you no output regarding errors, if there is one.
Here is a working example. Just define your x and y. Btw it seems like you can skip the for-loop and all that, if you use numpys `np.genfromtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',')`.

One of the problems is, that you need to call for the `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` Object. You do that with

```py
plt1 = ax1.plot([])
line1 = plt1[0].
```

In the following is full example.
To give yourself a nice output, you can use one of Jupyters Magic Functions `%matplotlib notebook`. With that you get the nice output right there in the notebook.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

%matplotlib notebook

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = x**2

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.set_xlim(min(x), max(x))
ax1.set_ylim(min(y), max(y))
plt1 = ax1.plot([])
line1 = plt1[0]
plt.grid()

def animate(i):
    #x,y = np.array([2, 2, 3, 5, 6], [3,5,4,6,7])
    line1.set_data(x[:i],y[:i])
    
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = 1000, interval=10)
```